# Can different set of records be randomly generated with the same seed

Tags: oracle, plsql, random-seed

I have 2 questions related to the package dbms_random in Oracle:

1. I wonder if there is a difference between initialize and seed in the dbms_random package.
   I have the need to randomize a fixed number of records from a larger set but I would like to have the records observed remain stable until I change the seed.
2. After reviewing the record, is there a way to generate a different set of records but still keep the seed, I wonder if there is a function to reset or reinitialize the package with the same seed?

Below is my sample code for illustration purpose. Can I generate a different set of records but still keep the original seed?

```
begin
--dbms_random.initialize(100);  
dbms_random.seed(100);  
SELECT *
FROM   (
    SELECT *
    FROM   table
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.value)
WHERE  rownum < 21;

end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with question 2. The whole point of a seed is that the RNG will generate the same set of random numbers. If you want a different set of records, use a different seed...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I wonder if there is a difference between initialize and seed in the dbms_random package"

Yes, there is a difference. `initialize()` is **deprecated** and is only  retained in DBMS_RANDOM for backwards compatibility. All new code should use `seed()`. This is [covered in the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_RANDOM.html#GUID-5A2A2D32-A638-4E61-BA2B-80FA11A0EED2).

> is there a way to generate a different set of records but still keep the seed

Not with the code sample you posted. That will set the seed each time, which will give you the same set of records each time. To get multiple sets of different records spawned from the same seed you need to separate the seed setting from the record generation.

Here is [a demonstration on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b9cc0e62279b81feb68d1074640b90e9)

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for the information and the demo.. This is exactly what I would like to find out.. I was confused about initialize and seed since I saw it producing the same results.. thought I missed something...